# jquery parent.html is not a function

Tags: jquery, parent

Complete newbie working with jQuery and am having a bit of a problem.

I have a table with some of the cells having a  in them (never more than one select per cell).

In the following code select is the  element that was passed to the function.  I'm trying to get the parent  so that I can remove the  and replace it with some html.

```
function submit_pick( select ) {
    var parent = select.parent().get(0);      
    select.remove();
    jQuery("#testdiv").html(parent.tagName);
    parent.html(parent.tagName);
}
```

`select.remove();` works as expected

`jQuery("#testdiv").html(parent.tagName);` also works as expected producing TD

`parent.html(parent.tagName);` does not work.  Firefox's web console gives an error parent.html is not a function.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  you might want to avoid using variable names that are also HTML tag names and JQuery function names (select, parent)... if nothing else it makes reading your code a bit confusing. :|

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the naming conventions in mind for easier readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.get(0)` returns a native `DOMElement` and  not `jQuery` object anymore, thus you need to wrap the `parent` inside `$()` (also the reason why `html()` is complained as not being a function, as `html()` belongs to jQuery object, not `DOMElement`):

```
jQuery(parent).html(parent.tagName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jQuery(parent).html(parent.tagName);
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent` is not a jQuery object anymore, you would have to use:

```
$(parent).html(parent.tagName);
```

Answer (score 0):

get returns a dom element not a jquery object. try

```
var parent = select.parent().eq(0);
```

`eq` gives you the jquery object at the index, which is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have done `.get(0)` which returns a DOM element, not a jquery object.

http://api.jquery.com/get/

you should use `jQuery(parent)` to be able to use the `.html()` method again.